# How to transition between "rooms" / virtual cameras on a button press?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make a game that navigates [like the example here](https://youtu.be/GxWqPMI1gZk?t=757):

[image]

I'd like it so that after combat, the player can push the button corresponding with an exit (left, right, up, down) and navigate like in this game.

Also I eventually hope to randomize each run of the game so it would hopefully have some flexibility outside of being hard baked.

I've seen examples of it being done with a player object and a collider, but the player won't actually be moving their character. I like this style of navigation because I think it still provides the joy of exploration for the player, but is more friendly of a navigation system for a novice like me.

How would I implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by making a component to associate with each room. Attach this to an empty game object at the position & orientation you want to view the room from.

This can also store information about which rooms are reachable from this one.

While we're at it, we can load it up with data about how the room should behave - like events to fire when the player reaches the room.

```
public class RoomView : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool visited;

    public RoomView northConnection;
    public RoomView eastConnection;
    public RoomView southConnection;
    public RoomView westConnection;

    public UnityEvent onEnterRoomFirstTime;
    public UnityEvent onEnterRoomSubsequent;

    public void Enter() {
        if(!visited && onEnterRoomFirstTime != null) onEnterRoomFirstTime.Invoke();

        visited = true;

        if(onEnterRoomSubsequent != null) onEnterRoomSubsequent.Invoke()
    }
}
```

For starters, you can wire up these references in the Inspector. Once you create your randomized generator, your generation routine can automatically wire-up adjacent rooms as it places them, or in a post-process scan over the level it's built.

Next we'll need a script on the camera to navigate between these rooms:

```
public class RoomCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    // Populate this in the Inspector to point to the first room.
    public RoomView currentView;

    // How long should a transition take, in seconds.
    public float transitionSeconds = 1f;

    // Where are we going next?
    RoomView _nextView;
    // How far are we through the transition, in the range 0 to 1?
    float _transitionProgress;

    // At the beginning, snap to our first room perspective, and enter that room.
    void OnEnable() {
        transform.position = currentView.transform.position;
        transform.rotation = currentView.transform.rotation;
        currentView.Enter();
    }

    // Each frame, either continue the transition, or accept input if not transitioning.
    void Update() {
        if(_nextView == null) {
            CheckInput();
        } else {
            ContinueTransition();
        }            
    }

    void CheckInput() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // You can add some extra checks here to ignore diagonals, if desired.
        // Or wire these up to be triggered by on-screen buttons instead of keyboard/gamepad.

        if(horizontal > 0.5f && currentView.eastConnection != null) {
            _nextView = currentView.eastConnection;
        }
        if(horizontal < -0.5f && currentView.westConnection != null) {
            _nextView = currentView.westConnection;
        }

        if(vertical > 0.5f && currentView.northConnection != null) {
            _nextView = currentView.northConnection;
        }
        if(vertical < -0.5f && currentView.southConnection != null) {
            _nextView = currentView.southConnection;
        }
    }

    void ContinueTransition() {
         // Accumulate progress based on time passed, clamping within the range 0...1.
        _transitionProgress = Mathf.Clamp01(
                                _transitionProgress
                                + Time.deltaTime / transitionSeconds);

        // Add some ease-in/out on the transition.
        // You can also use an animation curve to customize the easing.
        float blend = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, _transitionProgress);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(
                                currentView.transform.position, 
                                _nextView.transform.position,
                                blend);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
                                currentView.transform.rotation, 
                                _nextView.transform.rotation,
                                blend);

        // If we're finished transitioning, clear the transition state.
        if(_transitionProgress == 1f) {
            currentView = _nextView;
            _nextView = null;
            _transitionProgress = 0f;
            currentView.Enter();
        }
    }
}
```